# how to check user role on nestjs

Tags: nestjs, roles

I am making a project using nestjs.

I want to prevent users with a specific role in all controllers except for one controller.

I know, add `@UseGuard(RoleGuard)` `@Role(UserRole.Guest)` to each controller.

But I have a lot of controllers, and more will be added over and over again.

Is there a way to do it all at once like middleware?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not have a base controller that you extend and add the decorator to the constructor or something?

Also, check out `useGlobalPipes` to see if that can help with shared request logic.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Please understand that I am a beginner. If it's not rude, can you show me some code examples or that documentation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).